Exporting excel data with powershell for robocopy
I have on my hand a 300 lines excel sheet with source path and destpath for robocopy, to avoid copy paste all the path on a .bat file I try to make this powershell script:
# Import the Excel module
Import-Module ImportExcel

# Path to the Excel file
$excelPath = 'classeur.xlsx'

# Import data from the Excel file and check for null values
$data = Import-Excel -Path $excelPath
if ($data -eq $null) {
    Write-Host "No data was imported from the file. Please check if the file is empty."
    return
}

# Display imported data for verification
Write-Host "Imported data preview:"
$data | Format-Table -AutoSize

# File to store the source and destination paths
$outputFile = 'robocopy.txt'
if (Test-Path $outputFile) {
    Remove-Item $outputFile
}

# Iterate over each row of data
foreach ($row in $data) {
    $source = $row.Source
    $destination = $row.Destination

    # Check if either source or destination is empty
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($source) -or [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($destination)) {
        Write-Host "Empty source or destination found, skipping..."
    } else {
        # Format the line to write to the file
        $lineToWrite = "Source: `"$source`" - Destination: `"$destination`""
        Write-Host "Writing to file: $lineToWrite"
        $lineToWrite | Out-File -FilePath $outputFile -Append -Encoding UTF8
    }
}

Write-Host "All lines processed. Paths are stored in $outputFile"

I of course make a copy of the excel file and reconstrcut it to make it simple for the script to read
An example of the construction



Source
Destination




Sourcefilepath
Destination filapath


Sourcefilepath
Destination filapath



The result I'm expecting is the following
SET _source1="Filepath to source"

SET  _destsge1="Filepath to destination"

SET _source2="Filepath to source"

SET  _destsge2="Filepath to destination"

ETC...

The result I'm currently having
Empty source or destination found, skipping...
Empty source or destination found, skipping...
Empty source or destination found, skipping...
Empty source or destination found, skipping...

What did I check:

That the excel was correctly read by powershell, which is the case.
My PSVersion which is 5.1.22621.2506
Execute the script has administrator.
Excel version: Version 2403 (Build 17425.20146)

I want to point out that the txt file and the excel file are on the same folder has the script.
Can someone know why is the script unable to read the data I can't find anything specific to this issue:
Source I use: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2021/03/import-excel-file-in-powershell.html#:~:text=To%20import%20an%20Excel%20file%2C%20follow%20these%20steps%3A,the%20Excel%20file.%20For%20example%3A%20Import-Excel%20-Path%20C%3APathToExcelFile.xlsx
https://www.it-connect.fr/comment-manipuler-des-fichiers-excel-avec-powershell/

Separate the tests for source and destination filepaths into two new IF statements and check if only one of them is empty.

@MT1, well observed, indeed only the Destination part is empty the source get copied correctly

If your code now works please post it as an answer, this is an interesting way of reading an Excel file. HTH

It does not, the destination isn't getting copied @MT1

Please post a section of your Excel input file. Please, don't post a screenshot use this VBA code or use this website to create a Markdown table and edit it into your question.

And maybe show us the properties of $data with "$data | Get-Member"

With the help of @MT1, the issue was the use of elseif.
Instead it is better to use two if for this configuration.
Here the updated script that allow to get data from the excel and prepare robocopy command accordingly. note you have to manually enter the log file into the Robocopy.txt
The first line of your excel file must have source and Destination has header in order for the script to get the information
# Import the Excel module
Import-Module ImportExcel

# Path to the Excel file
$excelPath = 'classeur.xlsx'

# Import data from the Excel file and check for null values
$data = Import-Excel -Path $excelPath
if ($data -eq $null) {
    Write-Host "No data was imported from the file. Please check if the file is empty."
    return
}

# Display imported data for verification
Write-Host "Imported data preview:"
$data | Format-Table -AutoSize

# File to store the source and destination paths and robocopy commands
$outputFile = 'robocopy.txt'
if (Test-Path $outputFile) {
    Remove-Item $outputFile
}

# Writing initial setup commands to the file
$initialCommands = @(
    "chcp 1252 > nul",
    "@ECHO OFF",
    "SETLOCAL"
    "SET _LogFile=Robocopy.log"
    "SET _options=/E /XX /SEC /COPYALL /PURGE /R:2 /W:5 /LOG:%_LogFile% /TEE /V"
    "SET _options2=/E /XX /SEC /COPYALL /PURGE /R:2 /W:5 /LOG+:%_LogFile% /TEE /V"
)
$initialCommands | Out-File -FilePath $outputFile -Encoding UTF8

# Initialize a counter to create numbered variable names
$counter = 1

# Array to store ROBOCOPY commands
$robocopyCommands = @()

foreach ($row in $data) {
    $source = $row.Source
    $destination = $row.Destination

    # Check if the source is empty
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($source)) {
        Write-Host "Empty source found, skipping..."
        continue
    }

    # Check if the destination is empty
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($destination)) {
        Write-Host "Empty destination found, skipping..."
        continue
    }

    # Format the line to write to the file with SET command, including quotes around the paths
    $sourceLine = "SET `_source$counter=`"$source`""
    $destinationLine = "SET `_destst$counter=`"$destination`""
    $sourceLine | Out-File -FilePath $outputFile -Append -Encoding UTF8
    $destinationLine | Out-File -FilePath $outputFile -Append -Encoding UTF8

    # Determine which options variable to use
    $optionsVar = if ($counter -eq 1) { "_options1" } else { "_options2" } #Option 1 erase the content of the log file while option 2 write next to it
    # Prepare the ROBOCOPY command using the determined options variable and store it in the array
    $robocopyCommands += "ROBOCOPY %_source$counter% %_destst$counter% %$optionsVar%"

    # Increment the counter for the next pair of variables
    $counter++
}

# Append ROBOCOPY commands to the file after all SET commands
$robocopyCommands | Out-File -FilePath $outputFile -Append -Encoding UTF8

Write-Host "All lines processed. Paths and robocopy commands are stored in $outputFile"

